# Security risks and prevents for sending files over sockets

Tags: security, port, sockets

I am attempting to do Raspberry Pi development and at the moment, I'm normally writing all of the Python code on my laptop and then would have to use a SSH client to send the files across.

I've been thinking of a better, and quicker solution to this problem and thought that I could use *sockets* and build a client for my home computer, as well as a server client for the Pi. This, I could send the files by executing the programs and then telling the Pi what to do with them (for example, whether to run, or interpret the code) and then report any errors back that the program then has. I asked this question here [Python Sockets - Sending Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837913/python-sockets-sending-python-files?noredirect=1#comment27791621_18837913) which, a user suggested potential security risks involved in sending files that can be executable. I am looking for any advice in removing these potential security risks.

I have come up with the following:

When a user tries to connect to the server, whether it be from localhost or from an external IP, I have a list of valid IP's (My local IP is static, it does not change) and if the IP is on the list, then they are allowed to access and send files otherwise access is not granted.

A server log is recoded after each file is accepted and either interpreted or deployed and each connection is monitored, and, implementing a way for me to block any access should anyone attempt to gain access to the server.

I know there are probably more, so throwing it out there.. Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you doing when you "use a SSH client" to send files across? You can make that process pretty painless with `rsync` and [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) or similar. Maybe I'm missing something, but what you're suggesting sounds like a lot of effort for probably no benefit.

Comment: Could you clarify your exact question and denote it with a question mark as to avoid being closed for being to broad eg. "How can I secure my connection to my server to avoid man in the middle attacks? "

Comment: @jjlin Valid point, however, I want to do this as a project, though I could potentially use rsync